# Why does this image make 2 network requests on button click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, openseadragon

I am using an open-source web-based viewer in a Vue3 app. The image is not shown until the user clicks a "Open Image" button. It works good.

**However, does anyone know why the same image is making two network requests when the "Open Image" button is clicked?**

[image]

Here's is my minimal reproduction:

sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-xxxk9w?file=src/App.vue

`App.vue`:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Viewer from './components/Viewer.vue';
const show = ref(false);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="show = true">Open Image</button>
    <Viewer v-if="show" />
  </div>
</template>
```

`Viewer.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div ref="osdContainer" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import OpenSeadragon from 'openseadragon';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
const viewer = ref(null);
const osdContainer = ref(null);

const initViewer = () => {
  console.log('init Viewer');
  viewer.value = OpenSeadragon({
    element: osdContainer.value,
    tileSources: {
      type: 'image',
      url: 'https://ik.imagekit.io/pixstery/users%2F5cnu6iDlTsa5mujH2sKPsBJ8OKH2%2Fposts%2Fportrait-of-arabian-man_jjC2?alt=media&token=64fb0ae4-b0dc-4ead-b22e-292e55de1447&tr=f-auto,pr-true,q-80',
      buildPyramid: false,
    },
  });
};

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('mounting..');
  initViewer();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSeadragon thinks in tiled image pyramids, where most of the time you access the image metadata (resolution, and the like) and the actual tiles (bitmap data) separately.

Supporting actual images is the outlier in such world, and it's still handled as if image metadata and bitmap data would arrive from separate sources.

The first request you see comes from [`getImageInfo()`](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/blob/59083b766928ffefade84bc5b7c2ee775c685806/src/imagetilesource.js#L106) of `ImageTileSource`, the specialized class for supporting images:

```
        var image = this._image = new Image();

        [...]

        $.addEvent(image, 'load', function () {
            _this.width = image.naturalWidth;
            _this.height = image.naturalHeight;
            _this.aspectRatio = _this.width / _this.height;
            _this.dimensions = new $.Point(_this.width, _this.height);
            _this._tileWidth = _this.width;
            _this._tileHeight = _this.height;
            _this.tileOverlap = 0;
            _this.minLevel = 0;
            _this.levels = _this._buildLevels();
            _this.maxLevel = _this.levels.length - 1;

            _this.ready = true;

            // Note: this event is documented elsewhere, in TileSource
            _this.raiseEvent('ready', {tileSource: _this});
        });

        [...]

        image.src = url;             // <----------
```

and the second request is when the bitmap data is requested in [`_loadTile()`](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/blob/59083b766928ffefade84bc5b7c2ee775c685806/src/tiledimage.js#L1568):

```
      _loadTile: function(tile, time) {
        var _this = this;
        tile.loading = true;
        this._imageLoader.addJob({
          src: tile.getUrl(),           // <-------
```

this part of the code is a generic one, `TiledImage`, which is common for everything. And this is a weakness of current(*) OpenSeadragon: the generic code asks for an URL, and not for tile data. So it doesn't matter that the `ImageTileSource` above stores the entire image in its `_image` field (and even more (*)), the drawing code never asks for it, it wants and gets an URL, for which it issues a request.

[`getTileUrl()`](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/blob/59083b766928ffefade84bc5b7c2ee775c685806/src/imagetilesource.js#L177) of `TileImageSource` indeed provides that URL without any magics:

```
        var url = null;
        if (level >= this.minLevel && level <= this.maxLevel) {
            url = this.levels[level].url;
        }
        return url;
```

When mentioning "magic", I can think of usage of [`createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). Then you would download the image with `fetch()`, ask for `blob()`, do the `createObjectURL()`, and use that URL for both the `image.src =` line and return it in `getTileUrl()`.
So if you have your own OpenSeadragon copy, it would become something like

```
    getImageInfo: function (url) {
        [...]
        // image.src = url;
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                image.src = this.objurl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            });
    },
```

and

```
    getTileUrl: function (level, x, y) {
        return this.objurl;
    },
```

---

(*) And why this probably doesn't matter:

- Browsers have cache. You likely see the 2 requests because you have "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)". If you unmark the option, there will be a single request. At least it happens for me in Chrome
- They're working on it, see https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/pull/2148 and the `levels[]` thing in the original `getTileUrl()` (and `_buildLevels()` at the end of the file). `ImageTileSource` already stores the image and even an entire pyramid created from it, just it's not in use, yet.

Comment: Will investigate! Stay tuned !

Comment: That was it -- it simply was the fact I had "disable cache" checked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the same image is making two network requests when the "Open Image" button is clicked is that the `initViewer()` function is called every time when the **viewer.vue** component is mounted or re-rendered.

Look at what happens when the "Open Image" button is clicked,

1. the Viewer component is rendered and mounted
2. It triggers the `onMounted` hook and calls the `initViewer()` function.
3. Then it sends the first network request to load the image. Then, when the show value is changed to false (for example, when the component is unmounted or re-rendered), the Viewer component is destroyed and then re-rendered when the show value is changed back to true, triggering the `initViewer()` function again and causing another network request to load the image

To avoid this, you can modify your code to call the initViewer function only once, by adding a isViewerInitialized ref variable to track if the viewer has been initialized or not, and checking its value before calling initViewer

**UPDATE:**
I'm sorry, the above case is not the main cause of your trouble. OpenSeadragon is designed to load the image in a separate HTTP request when it is needed for "lazy loading"

When you click the "Open Image" button, the viewer component is loaded and the OpenSeadragon viewer initializes. At this point, the viewer does not yet have the image data and so it makes a separate HTTP request to fetch the image data from the server.

If you want to avoid this behavior and load the image data directly when the viewer is initialized, you can set the immediateRender option to true. This will cause OpenSeadragon to load the image data immediately when the viewer is initialized, instead of waiting until the image is needed.

Here's how you can modify your code to set the immediateRender option:

Source: https://openseadragon.github.io/docs/OpenSeadragon.html#.Options

```js
<script setup>
import OpenSeadragon from 'openseadragon';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const viewer = ref(null);
const osdContainer = ref(null);
const isViewerInitialized = ref(false);

const initViewer = () => {
  console.log('init Viewer..');
  viewer.value = OpenSeadragon({
    element: osdContainer.value,
    tileSources: {
      type: 'image',
      url: 'https://ik.imagekit.io/pixstery/users%2F5cnu6iDlTsa5mujH2sKPsBJ8OKH2%2Fposts%2Fportrait-of-arabian-man_jjC2?alt=media&token=64fb0ae4-b0dc-4ead-b22e-292e55de1447&tr=f-auto,pr-true,q-80',
      buildPyramid: false,
      immediateRender: true
    },
  });
  isViewerInitialized.value = true;
};

onMounted(() => {
  if (!isViewerInitialized.value) {
    initViewer();
  }
});
</script>
```

Personally, I wouldn't mind the two requests and keep the `immediateRender: false`. It's improving UX there for the lazy load.

Comment: Thank you. I tested this out and I still see 2 network requests? Can you check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-v5y2aj?file=src/components/Viewer.vue

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated my answer here.

Comment: Sorry, it still renders twice:( The reason why I don't want it to render twice is because these images can be large files and having it download twice is not good (especially for mobile).

Comment: I dont see it rendering twice now in the stackblitz though. there is only one request right? (one console.log is inside of of mounted in stackblitz but not appearing the same twice for me)

Comment: When you go to network tab in browser devtools, you can see the image is requested twice when you click the "Open Image" button. Can you confirm?

Comment: I still see one request in dev tool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252302/discussion-between-no-one-and-redshift).